# How to display html and xml content under one pre tag

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have developed on flask application and i want to display my content in one pre tag. Content is coming from db and it has some html tags and some xml tags. I want to display html tags as resolved and xml tags as normal code. I tried using safe filter but xml content is getting lost.

```
from flask import Flask ,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    str = """It is a long establishontent here', making it look like readable English. <a href="www.google.com">Open Google</a> 
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by layout.  

<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
    """
    return  render_template("index.html" , content = str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)**
```

**Teamplate is like this:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <pre>{{content |safe}}</pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I am getting output like this :**

It is a long establishontent here', making it look like readable English. [Open Google](https://www.google.com) 
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by layout.

Tove 
  Jani 
  Reminder 
  Don't forget me this weekend!

**What i expect:** 


 It is a long establishontent here', making it look like readable English. [Open Google](https://www.google.com) 
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by layout.

```
 <note><br>
  <to>Tove</to><br>
  <from>Jani</from><br>
  <heading>Reminder</heading><br>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body><br>
</note>
```

Comment: It is kind of hard to do if you are mixing html and xml tags together but if you are really hard pressed you can try looking at the [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library

Comment: @kellymandem Thanks for the help. With the help of bleach i am able to resolve this.